# CakePHP: Export index view to CSV file

Tags: php, csv, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have a mechanism in place to basically dump everything in a certain model to a CSV file.

```
public function export() {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //increase max_execution_time to 10 min if data set is very large
    //create a file
    $filename = "export_".date("Y.m.d").".csv";
    $csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    $results = $this->Requirement->find('all');
    // Column headings
    $header_row = array("Req #", "Identity", "Status", "Name", "Description", "Owner");
    fputcsv($csv_file,$header_row,',','"');

    // Loop to create CSV file rows
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        // Array indexes correspond to the field names in your db table(s)
        $row = array(
            $result['Requirement']['req_number'],
            $result['Requirement']['or_identity'],
            $result['Requirement']['req_status'],
            $result['Requirement']['mission_id'],
            $result['Requirement']['description'],
            $result['Requirement']['req_owner']
        );

        fputcsv($csv_file,$row,',','"');
    }

    fclose($csv_file);
```

This works when we need to do bulk exports. What I need to do now is dump only my index view to a CSV file. This is the code for my index function in my controller:

```
public function index(){

    if(!empty($this->request->data['Requirement'])) {
        $this->Session->write('Requirement', $this->request->data['Requirement']);
    } else {
        $this->request->data['Requirement'] = $this->Session->read('Requirement');
    }
    $options = array('Requirement.mission_id' => $this->request->data['Requirement']['mission_id']);

    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
    $this->set('requirements', $this->Paginator->paginate('Requirement', $options));
}
```

And these are the columns displayed in the view:

```
<?php foreach($requirements as $requirement): ?>
<tr>
    <td width="5%"><?php echo $requirement['Requirement']['req_number']; ?></td>
    <td width="15%"><?php echo $requirement['Requirement']['or_identity']; ?></td>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $status = ($requirement['Requirement']['req_status'] == 0 ? 'Open' : 'Closed'); ?></td>
    <td width="15%"><?php echo $requirement['ReqIdentity']['req_name']; ?></td>
    <td width="50%"><?php echo $requirement['ReqIdentity']['req_description']; ?></td>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $requirement['ReqIdentity']['req_owner']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The index view is filtered on mission_id. How can I use my export function to just do an export of what my index function outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation:

1. Move the code from your `export()` method to a `csv()` method, which creates a CSV file from the data passed inside a parameter, instead of retrieving it from the database:

   ```
   public function csv($results) {
       //code for your export() method, except for the line 
       //$results = $this->Requirement->find('all');
   }
   ```
2. Rewrite your `export()` method to:

   ```
   public function export() {
       $results = $this->Requirement->find('all');
       $this->csv($results);
   }
   ```
3. Add functionality to your `index()` action to detect an export condition:

   ```
   public function index(){

       if(!empty($this->request->data['Requirement'])) {
           $this->Session->write('Requirement', $this->request->data['Requirement']);
       } else {
           $this->request->data['Requirement'] = $this->Session->read('Requirement');
       }
       $options = array('Requirement.mission_id' => $this->request->data['Requirement']['mission_id']);

       $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

       if (!empty($this->request->params['named']['export'])) {
           $this->set('requirements', $this->Paginator->paginate('Requirement', $options));
       } else {
           $this->csv($this->Paginator->paginate('Requirement', $options));
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add the following line to your `index` view:

   ```
   <?=$this->Html->link('Export',$this->here . "/export:true")?>
   ```